# Entity and Table annotations. Understanding the exact differences between them

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

I am learning hibernate and have some questions about the differences between Entity and Table, and how they work together/independently?

**Case 1:**

```
@Entity
public class Person{
}

My understanding - 
Entity name - Person
Table name in db - person
```

**Case 2:**

```
@Entity(name = "people")
public class Person{
}

My understanding - 
Entity name - people
Table name in db - people
```

**Case 3:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="people")
public class Person{
}

My understanding - 
Entity name - Person
Table name in db - people
```

**Case 4:**

```
@Entity(name = "person")
@Table(name = "people")
public class Person{
}

My understanding - 
Entity name - person
Table name in db - people
```

**Case 5:**

```
@Table(name="people")
public class Person{
}

My understanding - 
Entity name - ??
Table name in db - people
```

Is my understanding of these five cases correct? Is there anything else I should know about the working of Entity and Table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Entity` is used to declare a class can be managed by Hibernate. It also defines the entity name through its `name` attribute which is the name that we refer to when writing JPQL/HQL queries. If the entity name is not specified , it is default to the unqualified name of that entity class.

For example :

```java
@Entity(name="People")
public class Person{
}
```

Then I need to use `People` to refer to this entity when writing a JPQL/HQL query :

```
select p from People p;
```

`@Table` defines the actual DB table name that an `@Entity` is mapped to through its name attribute. If it is not specified , its default value will be equal to the entity name (i.e `@Entity` 's `name` attribute)

Also `@Table` only make senses if `@Entity` is defined . Otherwise , just defining `@Table` without `@Entity` (i.e case 5) does not have any effect.

---

So to to summaries:

**Case 1:**

```java
@Entity
public class Person {

}

Entity name = Person
DB Table name = Person
```

**Case 2:**

```java
@Entity(name = "people")
public class Person {
}

Entity name = people
DB Table name  = people
```

**Case 3:**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="people")
public class Person{

}

Entity name = Person
DB Table name =  people
```

**Case 4:**

```java
@Entity(name = "person")
@Table(name = "people")
public class Person{
}

Entity name = person
DB Table name = people
```

**Case 5:  Invalid**

Comment: Please specify what is JPQL. Also table name will not be automatically converted to lower case?

Comment: JPQL is a common sense in the JPA world so i don't think I need to explicitly specify what is that. Also by common sense , as the JPA is intended can work with all database , i don't think it  make sense it will have logic that it will automatically convert a table name defined by user to lower case.

Comment: Sure Thanks a lot

Comment: Actually Hibernate has a facility to define a custom policy for default table/column/sequence/etc names via `ImplicitNamingStrategy`. In principle you can program it to name the table as the lowercase class name. However, it's an advanced topic and not JPA-compliant.